# Dynamically configure exclude_matches for content scripts in chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For content scripts in chrome extensions, you can specify `matches` and `exclude_matches` to control what pages they are injected in. This has to be specified in the manifest of the extension like this

```
{
  "name": "Color picker",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "exclude_matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["color_picker.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "color_picker.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

I was wondering if I could add `["http://www.yahoo.com/*"],`to `exclude_matches` as and when the extension is in use. This way, I can allow the user to control the `exclude_matches`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An extension cannot modify any local files, including the extension's `manifest.json`. Chrome offers an API for [optional permissions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permissions.html), but this does not include [Content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html).

You can manually create flexible patterns:

```
// In the content script:
var exclude = /^https?:\/\/(www\.)?yahoo\.com\//;
if (!exclude.test(location.href)) {
     // Run logic.
}
```

Regular expressions are very powerful for this purpose, though not necessary. Instead of `location.href`, other `location` properties, such as `location.host` can be used.

See also: [MDN: `window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).

Answer (score 2):

You can think of `exclude_matches` as "hard" limits on what your extension must *never* do -- in short, it sets permanent bounds on which types of pages your content script should not touch. There is no way to modify it on the fly, since it is intended to be permanent.

However, If you want to make it flexible, you need to do the injection progammatically. Google has [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi) on how to do this using `executeScript`.  You'll need to add you own exclusion logic with user-controlled list (and using the good advice from the other answer, perhaps).